# Is APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB a BQP-complete problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, bqp, approximation

I've read contradictory information: on the [Wikipedia page for BQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP), it is written without proof that "APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB is a BQP-complete problem", while I have read elsewhere (don't remember) that "it is usually assumed that are no BQP-complete problems".
There is a chapter in the 'Handbook of Natural Computing' entitled "BQP-complete problems" but it contains no BQP-complete problems, only PromiseBQP-complete problems.

So is APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB a BQP-complete problem? If not, shouldn't the page be corrected? is it a PromiseBQP-complete problem?

There is a similar [question about Hamiltonian simulation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/what-are-examples-of-hamiltonian-simulation-problems-that-are-bqp-complete) where there are answers stating that it is BQP-complete and others that it is not, but only PromiseBQP-complete, so the clarification probably would be useful there too. What is promised exactly?

Comment: I've updated the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Welcome to our community !!!

Answer (score 5):

In [BQP-Complete Problems](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-92910-9_46) by Zhang (2012)

> Like many [...] "semantic" complexity classes, **BQP** is not known to contain complete problems.What people usually study for completeness, in such a scenario, is the class containing the promise problems, that is, those decision problems for which the union of Yes and No input instances is not necessarily the whole set of $\{0,1\}$ strings."

Janzing and Wocjan in their paper "[A Simple PromiseBQP-complete Matrix Problem](http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/toc.2007.v003a004)" (2007) stated that:

> Certain complexity theoretic issues related to BQP are often blurred in the literature; therefore some clarifications seem to be in order. BQP is a class of languages. But in the literature, when people talk about **BQP** they often mean the promise-problem version (**PromiseBQP**). Exactly like with **BPP** and **AM**, **BQP** itself is not known to have complete problems, but **PromiseBQP** has complete promise problems, and that is adequate for most purposes.

You may find the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/35236) about semantic complexity classes helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Just to further @Egretta.Thula's answer, a portion of the Wikipedia article on the APPROX-QCIRCUIT-PROB mentions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and stated:

> Note that the problem does not specify the behavior if an instance **is not covered by these two cases.** (Emphasis added).

Here, *i.e.*, the promise gap is $\alpha-\beta$ between the probabilities of measuring $|1\rangle$ in the first qubit of the circuit.

But, as Janzing and Wocjan mention, the distinction is often elided over - especially when speaking about (promise) QMA-complete problems, which have a rich tradition in the literature as well.

It's perhaps (marginally) interesting that Janzing and Wocjan's initial [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606229) version of their paper didn't note the distinction between PromiseBQP and BQP - but, when [published](https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v003a004/) in the Theory of Computing, made sure to clarify this point.  The arXiv version of the [HHL](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171) paper doesn't mention the point about the PromiseBQP complexity class either, although they show that their algorithm is complete only for PromiseBQP as well.